# adding Adsense's In-Article Ads between images of blog post

Tags: plugins, images, html, adsense

My blog post contains only images like this

```
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-567 size-full" src="..myimage_src_01.." alt="" width="960" height="960" /><br/>
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-567 size-full" src="..myimage_src_02.." alt="" width="960" height="960" /><br/>
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-567 size-full" src="..myimage_src_03.." alt="" width="960" height="960" /><br/>
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-567 size-full" src="..myimage_src_04.." alt="" width="960" height="960" /><br/>
```

I've got script code form `Google Adsense In-Article Ads`

```
 <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins .....xxx....data-ad-layout="in-article"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Let's say I've 9 images in my blog post , I want to show this In-Article Ads after each end of 3 images .
Like this ..

```
<image>
<image>
<image>
<ads>
<image>
<image>
<image>
<ads>
<image>
<image>
<image>
<ads>
```

I've tried [Ad Inserter Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ad-inserter/) but it only have option for adding ads`after paragraph` .
How can I format my post to enable like this ??

Answer (score 1):

Probably premium version has the option. Otherwise, inserting Adsense related code in the Loop can be another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps clicking on the image when in the editor, then you will see the image alight choices. See this article: https://en.support.wordpress.com/images/image-alignment/